# Selective implicit animations in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

How can I selectively ignore implicit animation for properties? According to [this example](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions#Add-Animations-to-Individual-Views) by Apple I should be able to have multiple `.animation` modifiers, but it doesn't work in the example below:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isSelected = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: isSelected ? 350 : 100, height: 250)
                .animation(nil, value: isSelected) // stops all animation
                .foregroundColor(isSelected ? Color.red : Color.green)
                .animation(.spring(), value: isSelected)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isSelected.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried changing the order of operations, and it seems like only the first animation modifier is used. I am testing against iOS 16.

Answer (score 0):

Your example jumps from a narrow green rectangle to a wide red rectangle with no animation.

I assume from the way you are applying a spring animation that you want to animate the width change but not the color change. I couldn't get this to work using a single state variable either. I found that either there was no animation, or the color change was animated in addition to the width change.

Using two state variables gives you more control, although I still couldn't get it to work by applying selective `.animation` modifiers to the `Rectangle`. However, the following works:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isWide = false
    @State private var isRed = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(isRed ? Color.red : Color.green)
                .frame(width: isWide ? 350 : 100, height: 250)
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isRed.toggle()
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                isWide.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - the actual jarring animation I don't care about. This was an example to test why overriding animations doesn't work. I have ended up with a similar approach in my code where I use two states, but I wanted to see if there was a way to avoid this. The example article I linked to implied that this should work.